# How do OkHttp caches work?

Tags: java, okhttp

I recently made a change from my existing implementation of creating a new client for every request to one standard singleton client.

Now as i began reading into the docs, i found out that there's also a thing called cache which is being used. There was some content which said that having multiple caches trying to access the same cache directory may end up causing them stomping over each other and causing crashes.

The docs I'm looking at are in their github repo:

[okhttp recipes for regular issues faced](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes)

My questions:

I'm not specifically setting any cache or cache control for my client. Just a few timeout values and a connection pool. Will there be any caching done by default if i use a new request and response object for each call i make?

```
client = new Okhttpclient.Builder()
              . connectTimeout (10000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              .readTimeout(15000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              . connectionPool (new ConnectionPool ())
              .build();
```

The above client is set as singleton and returned to all calling servlets. The request is created as

```
  Request req = new Request.Builder()
                  .url(someurl)
                  .get()
                  .build();

  Response res = client.newCall(req).execute();
```

If so, will there be issues as the mentioned stomping part. I don't need caching at all as mostly I'm just writing stuff to another server and when I'm reading i do need it to be the current values and not caches one... So do i need to explicitly set the cache-control set to force-network or will my default no specified setting be the same?

**EDIT**: this is the excerpt from the [Response caching](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#response-caching) part of the docs

> To cache responses, you'll need a cache directory that you can read
>   and write to, and a limit on the cache's size. The cache directory
>   should be private, and untrusted applications should not be able to
>   read its contents!
>
> It is an error to have multiple caches accessing the same cache
>   directory simultaneously. Most applications should call new
>   OkHttpClient() exactly once, configure it with their cache, and use
>   that same instance everywhere. Otherwise the two cache instances will
>   stomp on each other, corrupt the response cache, and possibly crash
>   your program.

Comment: Please provide links to the docs you refer to. Interpretations vary.

Comment: Done, posted the link to the docs referenced

Comment: Where is the caching section? Is it too hard to be specific, so that people trying to help don't have to get information like pulling teeth?

Comment: There... I posted part which i read and which has now thrown me into a dilemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OkHttp cache directory is set for each client instance. What the doc is telling you is that you shouldn't configure multiple clients to use the same cache directory. Caching has to be enabled explicitly, and isn't enabled in the code snippet in your question.

Having configured caching on the client instance, you can control response caching for each request. See [Cache](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Cache.html).

Comment: So i don't need FORCE_NETWORK to be set in cache control and Currently my caching is off?

Comment: @Kushan I don't understand the question; do you understand it yourself? If caching is not enabled, what are you forcing on the network?

Comment: Yea i wasn't very clear on what the flag would've done. Understood. I guess my current system will work how i intend it then. Always not caching data.

Comment: Yea sorry, there was a minimum time before which i wasn't allowed to accept it. This is perfect. Thanks :) i tend to be paranoid about stuff i don't understand, you cleared it up pretty good